# If $u(x) = T(u)(x)$ on a subset and $T$ is Lipschitz is $u(x) = T(T(u))(x)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $T:H^1(\Omega) \to H^1(\Omega)$ be a Lipschitz continuous map. Let $\Omega_0 \subset \Omega$ be a subdomain contained in $\Omega$.

Suppose we are given a function $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that for all $x \in \Omega_0$, $$u(x) = T(u)(x).$$
Could it be that $u(x) = T(T(u))(x)$ whenever $x \in \Omega_0$?

It's not true I think when the first identity holds for an arbitrary point, but if it holds for a non-null set and we have continuity it may hold??

Comment: If $u$ a fixed function?

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, $u$ is a given fixed function.

Comment: No chance this can hold: consider $T(u)(x)=u(x+1)$ and $u(x)=\max\{x,0\}$ ( and let me leave the choice of $\Omega_0$ to you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T (v)(x)  = \int_\Omega v(t) dt - 1$ (a constant function). Let $u$ be a function which is zero in $\Omega_0$ with $\int_\Omega u =1$. Then

$$Tu(x) = u(x) = 0$$

on $\Omega_0$. But

$$T(T(u))(x) = -1$$

does not equal $u$ on $\Omega_0$.